# Put Avatar and icon on Top of page without React native Element Headers

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am trying to do something like this.

i am using React native Elements, and when i add the  components it brings something like a very blue header, hence disrupts other screens and i would not want the blue header on all the screens.

Now i am looking for a way to have the avatar on the top left and the "+" sign on the top right without the blue header stuff showing.

This is what it looks like when i removed the header from React native Elements

[image: Screenshot-1667730102.png]

And this is what the source code looks like so far

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Avatar, Icon} from '@rneui/themed';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Avatar
        small
        rounded
        source={{
          uri: 'http://www.usanetwork.com/sites/usanetwork/files/styles/629x720/public/2016/07/mrrobot_s2_cast_rami-malek2.jpg',
        }}
        onPress={() => console.log('Left Clicked!')}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
      />

      <Icon
        name={'add-circle-outline'}
        color={'#00BB23'}
        size={32}
        onPress={() => console.log('Right Clicked!')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Is there something i am not doing rightly? Pls advice, i need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Once again , I got it to work.

I used the header and set the parameters to 'Transparent' and it works fine, then I used npm to install this package react-native-safe-area-view

like so `npm i react-native-safe-area-view`

Then using it inside my codes , it worked fine.

Codes for example

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {useSafeArea} from 'react-native-safe-area-view';

const ProfilePage = () => {
  const safeArea = useSafeArea();
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: safeArea.top}}>
      <Text>ProfilePage</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default ProfilePage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Then for the transparent header for React native Elements

I used this

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Avatar, Icon} from '@rneui/themed';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
        }}
        leftComponent={
          <Avatar
            small
            rounded
            source={{
              uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSiRne6FGeaSVKarmINpum5kCuJ-pwRiA9ZT6D4_TTnUVACpNbzwJKBMNdiicFDChdFuYA&usqp=CAU',
            }}
            onPress={() => console.log('Left Clicked!')}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
          />
        }
        rightComponent={
          <Icon
            name={'add-circle-outline'}
            color={'#00BB23'}
            size={32}
            onPress={() => console.log('Right Clicked!')}
          />
        }></Header>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

where I had to import `rneui/themed` using Npm packages

And everything works fine, as expected

Thanks everyone!